# Associative array logic--php

Tags: php

```
 $query="SELECT file_date,application,language,loc FROM table1 WHERE language!='total' AND module_id=306 ORDER by file_date";
     return(get_data($locdb_handler,$query));
}

function get_data($handler,$qry){
  $result=mysql_query($qry,$handler);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $data['data'][$row[0]]['data']['status'][$row[1]]+=$row[3];
    $data['total'][$row[0]]+=$row[3];
  }
```

$data['data'][$row[0]]['data']['status'][$row[1]]+=$row[3];----->
What does this line above convey.
There is a simple query....I wanna knw how we are mapping this...Please help

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In this sample they have used associative arrays.

Hope that helps.

---

You might want to add an actual question to your question if you want a real answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data['data'][$row[0]]['data']['status'][$row[1]]+=$row[3];
$data['total'][$row[0]]+=$row[3];
```

Is the same as

```
$data['data'][$row['file_date']]['data']['status'][$row['appliction']]+=$row['loc'];
$data['total'][$row['file_date']]+=$row['loc'];
```

except it's not an associative array, meaning it uses strings as array keys instead of numbers.  So $row[0] is the first column being returned by the query, $row[1] is the second, etc.